# Etymology of Persian suffix 'ـش-' (-eš)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, indo-european, persian, avestan

This suffix equivalent to English '-tion' or '-ment' occurs in many Persian words such as ستایش (setâyeš, "glory"), etc. But its ultimate etymology cannot be found anywhere. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B4#Persian) stops at linking it to the Middle Persian suffix '-' (-išn). I also found that some Avestan words end with '-' (-išnīh), which sounds related. Is there any further etymology to this suffix, probably extending to Proto-Indo-European?